# Updating an Entity through a Service

Tags: php, object-oriented-design

I'm separating my software into three main layers (maybe *tiers* would be a better term):

- Presentation ('Views')
- Business logic ('Services' and 'Repositories')
- Data access ('Entities' (e.g. ActiveRecords))

### What do I have now?

In Presentation, I use read-only access to Entities, returned from Repositories or Services, to display data.

```
$banks = $banksRegistryService->getBanksRepository()->getBanksByCity( $city );

$banksViewModel = new PaginatedList( $banks ); // some way to display banks;
                                               // example, not real code
```

I find this approach quite efficient in terms of performance and code maintanability and still safe as long as all write operations (create, update, delete) are preformed through a `Service`:

```
namespace Service\BankRegistry;

use Service\AbstractDatabaseService;
use Service\IBankRegistryService;
use Model\BankRegistry\Bank;

class Service
    extends AbstractDatabaseService
    implements IBankRegistryService
{
    /**
     * Registers a new Bank
     *
     * @param string $name                  Bank's name
     * @param string $bik                   Bank's Identification Code
     * @param string $correspondent_account Bank's correspondent account
     *
     * @return Bank
     */
    public function registerBank( $name, $bik, $correspondent_account )
    {
        $bank = new Bank();

        $bank
            -> setName( $name )
            -> setBik( $bik )
            -> setCorrespondentAccount( $correspondent_account );


        if( null === $this->getBanksRepository()->getDefaultBank() )
            $this->setDefaultBank( $bank );


        $this->getEntityManager()->persist( $bank );

        return $bank;
    }


    /**
     * Makes the $bank system's default bank
     *
     * @param Bank $bank
     * @return IBankRegistryService
     */
    public function setDefaultBank( Bank $bank )
    {
        $default_bank = $this->getBanksRepository()->getDefaultBank();  

        if( null !== $default_bank )
            $default_bank->setDefault( false );

        $bank->setDefault( true );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### Where am I stuck?

I'm struggling about **how to update** certain fields in `Bank` Entity.

**Bad solution #1**: Making a series of setters in `Service` for each setter in `Bank`; - seems to be quite reduntant, increases `Service` interface **complexity** and proportionally decreases it's **simplicity** - something to avoid if you care about code maitainability. I try to follow **KISS** and **DRY** principles.

**Bad solution #2**: Modifying `Bank` directly through it's native setters; - really bad. If you'll ever need to move modification into the `Service`, it will be pain. Business logic should remain in Business logic layer. **Plus**, there are plans on logging all of the actions and maybe even involve user permissions (perhaps, through decorators) in future, so **all modifications should be made only through the `Service`**.

**Possible good solution**: Creating an `updateBank( Bank $bank, $array_of_fields_to_update)` method; - makes the interface as simple as possible, but there is a problem: one should **not** try to manually set `isDefault` flag on a Bank, this operation should be performed through `setDefaultBank` method. It gets even worse when you have **relations** that you don't want to be directly modified.

Of course, you can just limit the fields that can be modified by this method, but **how do you tell method's user** what they can and cannot modify? Exceptions?

Comment: What about a single updateBank() setter in Service, to which you pass an object which is a composite of all the Bank properties that you are allowed to update this way, and no other properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The decision I've come up with

I've made `setDefaultBank` a protected method and removed it from `IBankService` public interface. I've also created an `updateBank( $bank, array $fields )` method that filters the `$fields` array and calls corresponding setters on `Bank`. If a `default` field is encountered, it is checked to be equal to `true` and `setDefaultBank` is called. Any invalid elements in `$fields` cause an `\InvalidArgumentException` to be thrown.

```
/**
 * Updates Bank fields
 *
 * @param int|Bank $bank    Bank ID or instance
 * @param array    $fields  Associative array of Bank fields
 *
 * @return IBankRegistryService
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function updateBank( $bank, array $fields )
{
    if(    false === $bank instanceof Bank
        && 0 < intval( $bank ) )
    {
        /** @var $bank Bank */
        $bank = $this->getBanksRepository()->find( $bank );
    }
    else
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException( '$bank should be either an ID or a Bank instance.' );

    foreach( $fields AS $key => $value )
    {
        switch( $key )
        {
            case 'bik':
                $bank->setBik( $value );
                break;

            case 'name':
                $bank->setName( $value );
                break;

            case 'correspondent_account':
                $bank->setCorrespondentAccount( $value );
                break;

            case 'default':
                if( !$value )
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException( 'Property "default" can only be equal to true' );

                $this->setDefaultBank( $bank );

                break;

            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException( 'Cannot change "' . $key . '" property of a Bank' );
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe CQRS is worth looking at for you.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

More specifically:

> Interacting with the command-model naturally falls into commands or events, which meshes well with Event Sourcing.

So in this pattern, you send updates to the domain model using commands sent via. events.

Comment: how does this answer the question asked, "how to update certain fields in `Bank` Entity.... how do you tell method's user what they can and cannot modify?"

Comment: He came up with 2 bad solutions and 1 possible good solutions. I referenced another possible good solution which is in use by others, and which he can search for. As I understood the question, he was looking for ways to update a Bank and event sourcing is one such way.